# 'java class name' command not working, is there any change in recent version?

Tags: java, java-11

If I remember correctly

1. `javac filename.java` -> compile and generates classname.class(es)
2. `java classname` without .class extension

But when I try `java filename.java` executes successfully while `java classname` command  gives the following error ,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

**java -version**

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

`javap HelloWorld.class` is giving below output

```
Compiled from "HelloWorld.java"
public class HelloWorld {
  public HelloWorld();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

1. `java HelloWorld.java` -> executes fine, no class file generated.
2. `java HelloWorld` ->  didn't execute.

Any idea why the program is behaving like this?

Comment: Yes, this is a change; introduced in.. release 12, I think? `java foo.java` is short for `javac foo.java && java foo`, more or less.

Comment: Does `java -cp . HelloWorld` work for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it works, so they basically removed current folder from class path that is why java HelloWorld was not working?

Comment: @JishnuPrathap: odds are that you have a `CLASSPATH` defined in your environment and that's the only change. Try `echo %CLASSPATH%`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes there is class path variable .

Comment: @JishnuPrathap: if you don't specify a `-cp` then that variable is used, if it's present. *Otherwise* the current directory is used. The environment variable is tricky, because it's easy to miss. Its in your best interest to always specify the classpath explicitly using `-cp` to avoid problems like that (that's *usually* achieved by using a proper build system like Gradle).

Comment: “`javac filename.java` -> compile and generates filename.class” — **No.** `javac` compiles the input file, but it does *not* generate a `filename.class` output file. Rather, it generates one or more `classname.class` files, one for each class in the input file.

Comment: @KonradRudolph true, corrected the question

Answer (score 5):

After some help from some stackoverflow veterans in the comment section I was able to understand what went wrong.

The latest version of Java have introduced **launching single file source code directly using Java command.**

from [oracle docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html)

> To launch a single source-file program:
>
> java [options] source-file [args ...]

To run Helloworld.java, you can directly call execute `java Helloworld.java` it will execute the java program and gives output without generating `.class` file in the   current directory.

**Why old way of running java class file didn't work for me?**

I had a class path variable '`CLASSPATH`' in my environment, so when I execute `java HelloWorld` it is not looking for class in current directory. Give `java -cp .` to explicitly give current directory to classpath.

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

Credits: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?force_isolation=true),[Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer?force_isolation=true), [rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot?force_isolation=true)